# CollectD server system load look scary

Tags: unix, load, collectd

Please excuse my poor server skill here.

However, I just installed collectD on Linux (web server) about minutes ago and found that the system load look a bit scary.

All graphs (cpu, memory) look fine except this one.
Can you guys let me know if everything is ok given by the graph below?

http://oi43.tinypic.com/2q8ocht.jpg

If so, can you direct me how to read this graph or point me the source to do further research from here.

(does red line graph and the 100m dash look like something it's not suppose to be on the stable server?)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This site is primarily about programming questions.  Try asking your question on http://www.serverfault.com/ instead.

Comment: SE-site Unix & Linux might also be appropriate as this doesn't seem to be related to *professional* server maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100m (milli) means a loadavg of 0.1: your server is pretty fine!

Comment: Thanks Guys, I actually figure out and did the stress test. Everything is good.